# How to customise a virtual environment in Python correctly?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have to develop software with the use of several programs together, like Python 3.6 (with specific packages), WKHtmlToPdf and an embedded browser (based on CEF). I should be able to share all this together in one directory, so with a virutal environment of Python 3.6...

My question to you all is: how can I make the paths of a Python virtual env relative.

A second question I have is: is it possible to just activate the virtual env without changing cmd prompts and things? I tried to write a batch file which 1) starts the environment, 2) executes a Py script and 3) runs the embedded browser. That batch file failed after it started the virtual environment...

Comment: I don't understand what relative paths have to do with anything. And if you are having trouble with a script, you should post it asking with the exact error you receive.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just want to make my virtual env portable, so that it can run on several machines without changing anything and it would be nice if the env doesn't change command prompt properties, as that causes problems with one script I have written. I know that that is the problem...

Comment: That's not how you use a virtualenv. You create separate ones on each machine; but your code contains a requirements.txt so that you can install all the dependencies in one go. And it's still not clear what you mean by "change command prompt properties" or exactly what "problems" it causes, as you still have not shown the script or the error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman See the answer of phd. That's what I mean :) I am sorry for being so unclear!

Comment: @Brian I am not using Anaconda. It's allright, htere's more information in the answer below about what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> I should be able to share all this together in one directory, so with a virtual environment

Virtual environments are not portable (they must reside in the same directory on a computer where exist global Python), hence you cannot share a virtual environment.

> My question to you all is: how can I make the paths of a Python virtual env relative.

No, and you certainly don't need to do it.

> A second question I have is: is it possible to just activate the virtual env without changing cmd prompts

Yes, it's regulated in `bin/activate` script which you can edit to your taste.

> and things?

What "things"? Activating virtual environment means changing PATH, PYTHONPATH and so on, you certainly cannot use virtual environment without changing these and other things.

> That batch file failed

If you want us to help you should show us the essential parts of the batch and in what way it failed.

May be you need a different solution like a Docker image. Docker can be installed on Windows though it must be installed on the target computers.

There are also simpler solutions: [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/). They "compile" python scripts to .exe and accompany that .exe with Python interpreter (in a .dll) and library (in a .zip file). But if your program needs more DLLs you have to copy them to the target computer.

You can also take a look at [RVirtualEnv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RVirtualEnv). It allows to create **relocatable** virtual environments. I don't know if such envs can be copied to a different host, though.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Are there more options than just a docker image, as there is no docker available on the computers I have to install it at. It should be available on Windows, as it is a windows application...

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: I still don't see how I can do it. It was maybehandy if I would provide this info: it is a cgi program using flask which is opened in a PHPDesktop environment...

Comment: Compile it to .exe, debug on a host without Python, install as a CGI script at the target host.